# Wordpress - Login loop - wp-admin to wp-login

Tags: wordpress, redirect, authentication

I'm getting an error: my wp-admin page (where I login) is redirecting to wp-login again and again. Wp-degub shows

```
Notice: O método construtor chamado para WP_Widget em Widget_CF7 esta depreciado desde a versão 4.3.0! Utilize
__construct()
no lugar. in /home/u387890207/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 3916
Powered by WordPress
```

I tried some solutions but nothing worked out.

Comment: At least tell us what solutions you've already tried... And maybe a little more editing on your text would help understanding how that error occured. [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Solutions i tryed:
https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-fix-wordpress-login-page-refreshing-and-redirecting-issue/
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/264070/redirect-loop-when-trying-to-login-to-wp-admin
https://www.hostinger.com/tutorials/fix-wordpress-login-redirect-loop

Comment: If site is using Cloudflare see also https://wptest.means.us.com/cloudflare-wordpress-unable-login-https/

Comment: What have you done already? Did you play around with your `wp-config.php`? Did you implement a function into `functions.php` which changes the login url? Anything like that?